# Poisson process: probability in overlapping intervals

Tags: probability, poisson-process

> Let $(N(t),\ t\geq 0)$ be a Poisson counting process with rate $\lambda=1$.
>   Determine
>   \begin{equation}
> \mathbb{P}\left(N(1,4]=6,\ N(3,7]=13\right)\label{eq:one}\tag{1}
> \end{equation}

**Attempt:**

The intervals $(1,4]$ and $(3,7]$ obviously overlap, so I cannot use the
independent increment property directly.
Trying to get some intuition for the problem, I sought to instead consider the (disjoint) intervals
$(1, 3]$, $(3, 4]$, and $(4, 7]$ and then enumerate the particular outcomes in each interval, for which summing their probabilities will give $\eqref{eq:one}$, that is:

\begin{array}{c | c | c}
N(1,3] & N(3,4] & N(4,7] \\
\hline
6 & 0 & 13 \\
5 & 1 & 12 \\
4 & 2 & 11 \\
3 & 3 & 10 \\
2 & 4 & 9 \\
1 & 5 & 8 \\
0 & 6 & 7
\end{array}

So that:
\begin{equation}
\{N(1,4]=6,\ N(3,7]=13\} = \bigsqcup_{i=0}^{6}{\{N(1,3]=6-i,\ N(3,4]=i,\ N(4,7]=13-i\}}
\end{equation}

And so:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(N(1,4]=6,\ N(3,7]=13\right)&=\sum_{i=0}^6{\mathbb{P}\left(N(1,3]=6-i,\ N(3,4]=i,\ N(4,7]=13-i\right)} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^6{\mathbb{P}\left(N(1,3]=6-i\right)\mathbb{P}\left(N(3,4]=i\right)\mathbb{P}\left(N(4,7]=13-i\right)}
\end{align}

Since the intervals are disjoint. From this point I believe it is a matter
of replacing each probability with the Poisson PMF with the appropriate parameter for each interval and evaluating the sum. My questions are:

1. Is my intuition valid here?
2. If so, this seems to be a very brute force approach. Is there a deeper - or perhaps more concise - probabilistic interpretation of this problem?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Unfortunately there isn't a simpler method of doing this.